# PyCox: Feature transforms with DataFrameMapper

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error, valueerror, survival-analysis

I am trying to implement DeepSurv for survival analysis with the Python package [pycox](https://github.com/havakv/pycox).
The author of the package also provide also a [notbook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/havakv/pycox/blob/master/examples/cox-ph.ipynb) with a coding example so I tried to transfer the code to my data.
However, there seems to be a problem defining x_train due to their proposed Feature transforms with DataFrameMapper.

In the notbook it says:

```
cols_standardize = ['x0', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x8']
cols_leave = ['x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7']

standardize = [([col], StandardScaler()) for col in cols_standardize]
leave = [(col, None) for col in cols_leave]

x_mapper = DataFrameMapper(standardize + leave)

x_train = x_mapper.fit_transform(df_train).astype('float32')
x_val = x_mapper.transform(df_val).astype('float32')
x_test = x_mapper.transform(df_test).astype('float32')
```

In the notbook they are standardizing the 5 numerical covariates but I have nothing to standardize. So I changed the code into:

```
cols_standardize = []
cols_leave = df_train.columns.values.tolist()

standardize = [([col], StandardScaler()) for col in cols_standardize]
leave = [(col, None) for col in cols_leave]

x_mapper = DataFrameMapper(standardize + leave)

x_train = x_mapper.fit_transform(df_train).astype('float32')
x_val = x_mapper.transform(df_val).astype('float32')
x_test = x_mapper.transform(df_test).astype('float32')
```

But when I execute training the model this error occurs:

```
batch_size = 256
lrfinder = model.lr_finder(x_train, y_train, batch_size, tolerance=10)
_ = lrfinder.plot()

RuntimeError: expected device cpu and dtype Float but got device cpu and dtype Long
```

Is it maybe because of the batch_size? What does batch_size actually mean?

However, I also tried to skip the whole Feature transforms step, so I just changed my dataframes into floats:

```
x_train = df_train.astype('float32')
x_val = df_val.astype('float32')
x_test = df_test.astype('float32')
```

But then if I go on training the modell it says:

```
All objects in 'data' doest have the same type.
```

I am really confused how to prepare my data to use pycox. Especially this label transforms step with standardization appears really confusing. I would be glad for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the code. Try to upgrade pytorch, like suggested here https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2126

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32363740)